# How to safely convert a string containing escaped JSON to valid JSON?

Tags: c#, .net, json, string

I am communicating with a third party API that returns JSON responses as follows:

```
"{\"SomeResponse\":{\"FIrstAttribute\":8,\"SecondAttribute\":\"On\",\"ThirdAttribute\":{\"Id\":2,\"FirstName\":\"Okkie\",\"Name\":\"Bokkie\",\"Street\":\"\",\"StreetNumber\":null,\"PostCode\":\"\",\"City\":\"\",\"Country\":\"}}}"
```

It is kind of JSON... but as a String. Note the first and ending double quotes and of course all the escape slashes.

Currently, I solve this by String.Replacing the backslashes and the first and end quote. After that, I am able to parse it.

```
mystring.Replace("\\", "");
```

However, what if one of the attributes actually has an backslash as a value? For example:

```
\"SecondAttribute\":\"My Super Back Slash: \\ . That was it.\"
```

In that case, I would accidentally remove the backslash that should be there in the value.

Does anyone have a bright idea on how to parse this JSON String properly?

Comment: How are you seeing the version that you posted? Does it *actually* contain all those backslashes, or are you looking at it in the debugger? If you dump it to the console with `Console.WriteLine`, what does it look like?

Comment: No, it really actually contains all these slashes. Checked that already. It's not the debugger sadly.

Comment: I get this even when making an api request in the browser using Chrome.

Comment: Hmm. I had an idea, but it fails at column 227 (the end, I believe - `\}` isn't valid). Can you contact the API producer?

Comment: Oh, that might be me! I did a cut and paste from the large response and changed some attribute names. The real response ends with:

\"SeatNumber\":8}}}"

Comment: Ah. In that case, I might have an answer, but I'm no longer at a laptop. Will try in an hour...

Comment: This looks like the API's publisher has drastically misunderstood something and has published the C# string literal representation of a json string, without removing the escaping. I've seen this before in questions in chat where the asker hasn't understood that what the Visual Studio debugger shows you is an escaped representation that will work when pasted into C# as a string literal.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This is basically JSON encoded *as* a JSON string - after doctoring the end of your string very slightly, as per comments. It's not too hard to handle that in Json.NET, using `JToken.Parse` to effectively unescape first, then parsing the result:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string text = File.ReadAllText("test.json");
        JToken token = JToken.Parse(text);
        JObject json = JObject.Parse((string) token);
        Console.WriteLine(json);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{
  "SomeResponse": {
    "FIrstAttribute": 8,
    "SecondAttribute": "On",
    "ThirdAttribute": {
      "Id": 2,
      "FirstName": "Okkie",
      "Name": "Bokkie",
      "Street": "",
      "StreetNumber": null,
      "PostCode": "",
      "City": "",
      "Country": ""
    }
  }
}
```

That should be fine even with data containing backslashes, as I'd expect the backslashes to be encoded once again - but it would be worth double-checking that.

Comment: `var text = "{\"PersonName\":\"Gol\\ld\"}"` and it failed right at `JToken token = JToken.Parse(text);` with ` Bad JSON escape sequence: \l`. How did it work for you? Please share.

Comment: @SriReddy: That's invalid - to create a string with a backslash in, you'd need a double backslash in the JSON, which means a *quadruple* backslash in your string literal, e.g. `var text = "{\"PersonName\":\"Gol\\\\ld\"}";` But that's only in the literal, not in the JSON itself... the JSON only contains a double backslash.

Comment: @SriReddy: It's not entirely clear whether the second example in the OP's code is meant to be real, valid JSON written as C# source code - but it isn't. That JSON wouldn't parse, but that isn't the source representation of JSON encoding of text containing a backslash. Any valid JSON is fine.

Comment: For me this throws "Can not convert Object to String." when casting the token to a string.

Comment: @ShaunLuttin: Using what input? Note the "after doctoring the end of your string very slightly, as per comments". I've just tried it again, adding just `\"` at the end of the `Country` part at the end of the string, and it's fine.

Comment: @JonSkeet Here is a demo of the code not working: https://github.com/bigfont/StackOverflow/tree/master/NewtonSoftEscapedJson and this is the value in the `text` variable: `"{\r\n  \"data\": {\r\n    \"userId\": 0\r\n  },\r\n  \"success\": true,\r\n  \"statusCode\": 200\r\n}\r\n"`. It might be that the answer you provided does not work with control characters.

Comment: @ShaunLuttin: It's not clear whether you mean that the text actually has backslashes in or not. If it doesn't, you should just be using `JObject.Parse(text)`. This question is about a situation where the JSON is already encoded a second time as a JSON string.

Comment: it appears `Jtoken token` and `JObject json` contain the same data? Any reason why we're using both `Jtoken` and `JObject` if they contain the same data?

Comment: @Greg: No, in this case one is a wrapped version of the other.

Comment: @GregDegruy: No, the content of the token is a string which is valid JSON which is then parsed as a JObject.

Comment: @Greg: No, I think you've missed the overall point of this question.

Comment: Instead of (string) token, I had to use token.ToString()

Comment: @Andrew: So what happened when you used `(string) token`? I'd expect that to be okay... perhaps your context isn't the same as the one in the question.

Comment: Same error mentioned above, "System.ArgumentException: 'Can not convert Object to String.'" But using token.ToString() worked, no idea why :)

Comment: @Andrew: If you could create a gist of the code, or at least the JSON, I could probably help more. My guess is that, like Shaun, you don't *actually* have text which is a JSON-encoded string.

Answer (score 10):

By using Newtonsoft.Json, here is an example:

```
String json="{\"SomeResponse\":{\"FIrstAttribute\":8,\"SecondAttribute\":\"On\",\"ThirdAttribute\":{\"Id\":2,\"FirstName\":\"Okkie\",\"Name\":\"Bokkie\",\"Street\":\"\",\"StreetNumber\":null,\"PostCode\":\"\",\"City\":\"\",\"Country\":\"}}}";     

dynamic result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var JsonRequest = JToken.Parse(rawjson).ToString(Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None);
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow. Please so not just post code as answer, but also a small explanation what you are doing there. Except for the code is self explaining, which I dont see here

Answer (score 0):

Ugh... that's not JSON at all. It's a weird JSON-like imitation, but a pretty nasty one. I think you're doing the right thing.

The only thing that I might do is do the replace operation on pairs of characters rather than just the single escape char:

`myString.Replace(@"\""", @"""); // replace \" with "`

This will allow you to safely preserve the nested "\" chararcters, so that the filtered JSON looks like:

`field_blah: "root\branch\sub-branch"`

I strongly advise undertaking a detailed review of the "JSON" text and ensuring that this is the only paired sequence you need to worry about. If you have other pairings, handle them in the same manner as outlined above.