# Parse html from json in c#

Tags: c#, html, json, parsing

We have developed class with following procedures which contacts yandex translation `api` and submit post message for translation html from english to german (etc..) language.

The reason why we are sending html is that we need to translate values in title attributes and urls in document.

Libraries used are **RestSharp and HtmlAgilityPack**.

Procedure is simple as is :

```
private RestClient _client = new RestClient("https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json");
private RestRequest request = new RestRequest("translate");
request.AddParameter("key", key);
request.AddParameter("text", textToTranslate);
request.AddParameter("lang", from + "-" + to);
request.AddParameter("format", "html");
RestResponse response = (RestResponse)_client.Execute(request);
var result = response.Content;
```

so far so good, we are getting response from yandex. 
Now the fun begins :

```
HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
dynamic typedResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(result);
string text = Convert.ToString(typedResult.text);
text = HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlEntity.DeEntitize(text);
htmlDoc.LoadHtml(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(text));
```

First we had lot of exceptions becouse yandex returns html as array in text property of response, html encoded for json.

```
    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlEntity.DeEntitize(text)
```

solve this problem. Now we have lot of \ and \n\r and escape characters in html document, HtmlAgility pack can parse but we are getting wrong values for href attributes in `a` tags.

We need those attributes `href` to change url from english to german url. Unfortunately, href attribute is encoded with quotation marks
like so

and forward slash are escaped like :

```
<div>Hello<\/div>
```

,so there is a lot of fight to remove those chars, as I have run out of ideas how to deal with this.

Question is:

What is the proper way to parse json encoded html?

I am getting from yandex this response :

```
{{
  "code": 200,
  "lang": "en-fr",
  "text": [
    "<p class=\"hidden-sm-down\">\n La raison de la popularité pour les hors-bord de l'Atlantique 670,.. Elaphites.\n </p>\n<div class=\"btn-group\">\n<a href=\"/en/speedboats/atlantic-sun-cruiser-730\" title=\"Atlantic Sun Cruiser 730\" class=\"btn btn-info btn-responsive waves-effect waves-light\">Détails</a>\n <a href=\"/en/speedboats/atlantic-sun-cruiser-730?itinerary=exp-1-7303-ie&amp;option=half-day\" title=\"Atlantic Sun Cruiser 730\" class=\"btn btn-info btn-responsive waves-effect waves-light\">Les îles elaphites demi-journée</a>\n <a href=\"/en/speedboats/atlantic-sun-cruiser-730?itinerary=exp-1-7303-ie&amp;option=full-day\" title=\"Atlantic Sun Cruiser 730\" class=\"btn btn-info btn-responsive waves-effect waves-light\">Les îles elaphites journée complète</a>\n <a href=\"/en/speedboats/atlantic-sun-cruiser-730?itinerary=exp-1-7306-im\" title=\"Atlantic Sun Cruiser 730\" class=\"btn btn-info btn-responsive waves-effect waves-light\">L'Île De Mljet</a>\n <a href=\"/en/speedboats/atlantic-sun-cruiser-730?itinerary=exp-1-7316-ks\" title=\"Atlantic Sun Cruiser 730\" class=\"btn btn-info btn-responsive waves-effect waves-light\">L'Île De Korcula</a>\n <a href=\"/en/speedboats/atlantic-sun-cruiser-730?itinerary=exp-1-7316-hv\" title=\"Atlantic Sun Cruiser 730\" class=\"btn btn-info btn-responsive waves-effect waves-light\">Hvar</a>\n </div>\n                \n                </div>"
  ]
}}
```

So I want to get **(decoded)** value of `text` json object and pass it to the HtmlAgility pack to translate title attributes.

How I can get clean html without escape chars and quotation marks?

Regards,
Frano Hartman.

Comment: Please show sample of the text you want to encode. Or are you trying to decode? It would be helpful if you provided sample data: the data you get from yandex, and the desired result.

Comment: Hi Jim : I have edited question with data response from yandex. Thanks...

Comment: Seems like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26404649/how-to-safely-convert-a-string-containign-escaped-json-to-valid-json might have the answer you're looking for.