# Newtonsoft escaped JSON string unable to deseralize to an object

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization, json-deserialization

**Question background:**

I am receiving a JSON response via a HttpResponseMessage, as shown:

```
var jsonString= response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

This is giving me the following simple escaped JSON string result:

```
"\"{\\\"A\\\":\\\"B\\\"}\""
```

**The problem:**

I am using Newtonsoft to try and deserialize this to a model:

```
SimpleModel simpleModel= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SimpleModel>(jsonString);
```

The Class model of `SimpleModel`:

```
 public class SimpleModel
 {
     public string A { set; get; }
 }
```

The conversion is giving me the following error:

```
An exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: Error converting value "{"A":"B"}" to type 'PyeWebClient.Tests.ModelConversionTests+SimpleModel'. Path '', line 1, position 15.
```

**The JSON I receive back from the Task Result is valid, so I cannot understand what the problem is to cause the conversion error, what is the correct way to format the JSON string so it can be converted to its C# model type?**

Comment: Is there an inner exception present with might give you more details?

Comment: So if your serialized JSON is serialized again, you could also just deserialize it twice: `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SimpleModel>(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>("\"{\\\"A\\\":\\\"B\\\"}\""))`. Of course it would be better to avoid serializing it twice in the start.

Comment: There are extra quotes in your source string, which are not valid json. Valid json would be {"A":"B"}, without the double quotes wrapping it. Either remove the extra quotes before deserializing, or double check the serialization step as mentioned by @ckuri

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to safely convert a string containing escaped JSON to valid JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26404649/how-to-safely-convert-a-string-containing-escaped-json-to-valid-json)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You json appears `serialize` twice.

**1)** So you have to first deserialize into string and then again deserialize into your `SimpleModel` like

```
string json = "\"{\\\"A\\\":\\\"B\\\"}\"";

string firstDeserialize = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(json);

SimpleModel simpleModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SimpleModel>(firstDeserialize);
```

**Output:**

[image]

**2)** If you don't want to deserialize twice then parse your json into `JToken` and then again parse it into `JObject` like

```
string json = "\"{\\\"A\\\":\\\"B\\\"}\"";

JToken jToken = JToken.Parse(json);
JObject jObject = JObject.Parse((string)jToken);

SimpleModel simpleModel = jObject.ToObject<SimpleModel>();
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Question:** How it will be serialize twice?

**Answer:** When you return your result from `HttpResponseMessage` you successfully serialized your result and after reading this result from `ReadAsStringAsync` then this method again serialize your result that already serialized.

Comment: @Dev, view the answer might be it help you :)

Comment: This answer is especially helpful when the values in json also contain doublequotes. All answers saying that you need to replace or unescape will cause an error in that case.

Comment: @exrezzo Glad to hear :)

Comment: Great answer! Rescued me from more hail pulling :D

Comment: Thank you er-sho! Not sure what was going on on my end but what used to work on Xamarin (serializing/deserializing) no longer works on .NET MAUI, the received Json on the client was escaped twice (for some reason). Your solution works and got me going again after spending a day digging around trying to solve it. Thank you kindly.

Comment: @RichardD. Your words are appreciated...

Answer (score 2):

you can just unescape the json string back to normal string and than use `DeserializeObject`

```
 string jsonString = "\"{\\\"A\\\":\\\"B\\\"}\"";

 jsonString = Regex.Unescape(jsonString); //almost there
 jsonString = jsonString.Remove(jsonString.Length - 1, 1).Remove(0,1); //remove first and last qoutes
 SimpleModel simpleModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SimpleModel>(jsonString);
```